# In Hive, how do I test if I have select access to a table?

Tags: hive, authorization

If I try to select a hive table I'll get an authorization exception if I don't have permission.

Can I quickly check if I have select access to a table or database without effectively trying to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the explain command

```
explain authorization select * from table;
```

Can see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5961